# Building LAPACK 3.7.1 on 64bit Ubuntu 16.04 ignores 32bit flags, using make

Tags: c, ubuntu, cmake, gfortran, lapack

I'm trying to build the latest LAPACK library (3.7.1), from netlib, on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit, for a 32bit application (not the best idea, I know, but I'm restricted to this operating system). My research into doing this showed that I should add the -m32 flags to the gfortran and gcc flags. The libraries are built, but remain 64bit.

When trying to link, the following error is displayed for each object in the libraries:

```
i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `x' is incompatible with i386 output
```

The instructions for installing LAPACK says that only the make.inc file needs to be modified, but they do seem to be somewhat out of date.

So far I've tried adding the -m32 flag to gcc CFLAGS and gfortran OPTS, as well as adding -melf_i386 to the gfortran loader options, with no change in the output files format.

Here's the make.inc I'm using, at the moment:

`####################################################################
#  LAPACK make include file.                                       #
#  LAPACK, Version 3.7.1                                           #
#  June 2017                                                       #
####################################################################

SHELL = /bin/sh

#  CC is the C compiler, normally invoked with options CFLAGS.
#
CC     = gcc
CFLAGS = -O3 -m32 -fPIC

#  Modify the FORTRAN and OPTS definitions to refer to the compiler
#  and desired compiler options for your machine.  NOOPT refers to
#  the compiler options desired when NO OPTIMIZATION is selected.
#
#  Note: During a regular execution, LAPACK might create NaN and Inf
#  and handle these quantities appropriately. As a consequence, one
#  should not compile LAPACK with flags such as -ffpe-trap=overflow.
#
FORTRAN = gfortran
OPTS    = -O2 -m32 -frecursive -fPIC
DRVOPTS = $(OPTS)
NOOPT   = -O0 -m32 -frecursive -fPIC

#  Define LOADER and LOADOPTS to refer to the loader and desired
#  load options for your machine.
#
LOADER   = gfortran
LOADOPTS = -melf_i386

#  The archiver and the flag(s) to use when building an archive
#  (library).  If your system has no ranlib, set RANLIB = echo.
#
ARCH      = ar
ARCHFLAGS = cr
RANLIB    = ranlib

#  Timer for the SECOND and DSECND routines
#
#  Default:  SECOND and DSECND will use a call to the
#  EXTERNAL FUNCTION ETIME
#TIMER = EXT_ETIME
#  For RS6K:  SECOND and DSECND will use a call to the
#  EXTERNAL FUNCTION ETIME_
#TIMER = EXT_ETIME_
#  For gfortran compiler:  SECOND and DSECND will use a call to the
#  INTERNAL FUNCTION ETIME
TIMER = INT_ETIME
#  If your Fortran compiler does not provide etime (like Nag Fortran
#  Compiler, etc...) SECOND and DSECND will use a call to the
#  INTERNAL FUNCTION CPU_TIME
#TIMER = INT_CPU_TIME
#  If none of these work, you can use the NONE value.
#  In that case, SECOND and DSECND will always return 0.
#TIMER = NONE

#  Uncomment the following line to include deprecated routines in
#  the LAPACK library.
#
#BUILD_DEPRECATED = Yes

#  LAPACKE has the interface to some routines from tmglib.
#  If LAPACKE_WITH_TMG is defined, add those routines to LAPACKE.
#
#LAPACKE_WITH_TMG = Yes

#  Location of the extended-precision BLAS (XBLAS) Fortran library
#  used for building and testing extended-precision routines.  The
#  relevant routines will be compiled and XBLAS will be linked only
#  if USEXBLAS is defined.
#
#USEXBLAS = Yes
#XBLASLIB = -lxblas

#  The location of the libraries to which you will link.  (The
#  machine-specific, optimized BLAS library should be used whenever
#  possible.)
#
BLASLIB      = ../../librefblas.a
CBLASLIB     = ../../libcblas.a
LAPACKLIB    = liblapack.a
TMGLIB       = libtmglib.a
LAPACKELIB   = liblapacke.a`

As this is likely relevant, I have installed the gfortran, gcc, g++ -multilib packages, and the application I'm attempting to link the libraries to successfully does so with other 32bit libraries (libjpeg:i386 and libquadmaths:i386, for example).

I've spent quite a few hours looking for a solution, and would appreciate any insight that can be given!

Cheers,

Cavusa